# Configuration for enabling Ehcache DiskStore

Tags: java, ehcache

I referred [this](https://www.mkyong.com/ehcache/ehcache-hello-world-example/) for configuring disk store for Ehcache.

Below is my configuration. But this does not seem to work. I do to see any file in `d:\cache`. **Am I missing something ?**

```
   <diskStore path="d:\\cache" />

    <cache name="cache1"
            maxEntriesLocalHeap="10"
            maxEntriesLocalDisk="10000"
            eternal="false"
            diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20"
            timeToIdleSeconds="1" timeToLiveSeconds="2"
            memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="FIFO"
            transactionalMode="off">
            <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
        </cache>
```

Comment: maybe some permission problem to write in that path? You can alternatively use these properties as paths `user.home`, `user.dir`, `java.io.tmpdir`

Comment: Can you indicate the Ehcache version you are using and the sequence of operation you do between creating, putting mappings, shutting down and checking for files?

Comment: `Version: 1.6 Beta` (Yes it is old, but I can't change). I got this working today. it was not respecting the diskStorePath. Instead it was creating in java.io.tmpdir. Thanks for your help. I was using `CacheManager.getInstance()`, so, it was not reading this XML.